# Which SD and n to use in weighting meta-analyses (level of replication...)

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, meta-analysis

I am conducting a meta analysis looking at the fitness of animals (e.g. survival) in altered habitats using lnRRs (comparing control wetlands and impacted wetlands).

I'm having issues calculating variances for weighting. My issue lies largely in the unit of replication of interest and subsequent SD and n values to use.

Some studies use a single control wetland and a single impact wetland. Then they may have 100 microcosms that simulate each wetland and within each they have a tadpole and monitor survival.

Var(RR) = *control*(SD^2/(N*X^2)) + *impact*(SD^2/(N*X^2))

If I focus on the wetland level, n = 1 and I can't calculate a SD.

If I focus on the individual level, n1 = 100 and n2 = 100, so I can.

However, if I focus on the individual, I feel that the weight given to study A (1 control, 1 treatment wetland; 100 microcosms/individuals per wetland) will be equal to study B (100 control, 100 treatment wetlands; 1 microcosm/individual per wetland). And in fact, the weight might even be greater for A since one could assume lower variability between "replicates" from the same wetland.

Does anyone have advice not how to deal with this?

SD = variance among individuals within each wetland, with n = individuals

SD = variance among individuals within each wetland, with n = wetlands

SD = variance among individuals within a study, with n = wetlands

SD = variance among wetlands within a study, with n = wetlands

(If n=1 then use alternate variance estimate calculation)

Thanks in advance for any help

-M